# How to join two tables showing max() of other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the tables Fruits:

```
|ID|FruitName|
|1 |Banana   |
|2 |Orange   |
|3 |Apple    |
```

And I also have the table Sales:

```
|ID|Month|Sold|
|1 |Jan  |20  |
|1 |Feb  |10  |
|1 |Mar  |30  |
|2 |Apr  |15  |
|2 |Jan  |25  |
|3 |Jul  |25  |
|3 |Jun  |18  |
```

Now I want to Display this

```
1|Banana|Mar|30|
2|Orange|Jan|25|
3|Apple |Jul|25|
```

Comment: does you table store month as `varchar`?

Comment: try to replace it with `int` where 1=Jan, 2=Feb and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `fruit` table with `sales` once to get the month and then again to `sales` table to get the `maxSold` count using which you can filter out the unneeded records on which the `sold` count is not equal to the `maxSold`.

```
SELECT  f.id, f.name, s.month, maxSold
FROM fruit f LEFT JOIN sales s ON f.id = s.id 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT id,  max(sold) maxSold FROM sales 
             GROUP BY id) salesMax ON salesMax.id = f.id
WHERE s.sold = maxSold
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/912d5/27)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.id
    ,f.fruitname
    ,s.month
    ,s.sold

FROM fruits f
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.*
    FROM Sales a LEFT JOIN Sales b ON a.Id = b.IdAND a.Sold < b.sold
    WHERE b.Sold IS NULL) AS s 
ON s.id = f.id
```

The inner left join between sales tables are getting the max values, then outer left join is just adding the fruit names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.id, a.month, a.sold, c.fruitName
from   sales a,
       (
         select month, max(sold) sold
         from   sales
         group by month
       ) b,
       fruits c
where  a.month = b.month AND a.sold = b.sold AND a.id = c.id
```

Answer (score -1):

You may not need the distinct but this should be somewhat close for MySQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    F.ID
    , F.FruitName
    , M.Month
    , MAX(M.Sold) AS Sold
FROM 
    Fruits F
JOIN
    Sales S ON
    F.ID = S.ID
GROUP BY F.ID, F.FruitName, M.Month, M.Sold
```

Answer (score -1):

I can go like this in my SQL statement.

```
SELECT
 fruits.ID,
 fruits.FruitName,
 Sales.Month,
 MAX(Sales.Sold) as MAX
FROM
 fruits
LEFT JOIN Sales
 ON fruits.ID = Sales.id
GROUP BY 
fruits.id
```

Comment: `group by` clause should include other non-aggregate select columns. This will raise an error.

Comment: hi @mshsayem can you give me a link so I can know what you're talking about. Thank you :)